# JavaFX, client GUI, 2 instances causes second socket to be NULL

Tags: multithreading, sockets, user-interface

I've coded a client program that communicates with my arduino server. It had a swing button and a methog that ran a loop checking for any input from the server. I tried it with multiple instances running from different or/and the same IP and everything was fine. Now I tried implementing that same method for the socket in a app with JavaFX GUI. After I read here and there that it needs to be on a separate thread I did it as instructed and it seems to be working just fine. If I try to launch a second instance of it though,it imidiately throws NullPointerException on the line where i check **socket.isConnected() && !Socket.isClosed().** The first instance continues to work just fine, but the other one just stays with the GUI open.

As I've done it with the same class but not on a new thread and with swing button, I can say that the problem is not on the server side.

I need to be able to launch as many instances of the program as I want while they all keep an open socket at all times. Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Update: I tryed recalling the initiation in the loop when socket is lost. It seems that the socket closes right after it is opened.

Here is the Class for the client:

```
package panelSouth;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Networking implements Runnable{

    static Socket socket;
    static OutputStreamWriter out;

    public void run() {

        //Initializing socket - IP/PORT
        String host = "192.168.1.178";
        int port = 2015;

        boolean connected=true;
        do{
            try{
                socket = new Socket(host,port);
            }
            catch(Exception unknownHostException){
                connected=false;
                System.out.println("Connecting to host...");
            }
        }while(connected==true);
        System.out.println("Connection is a success!");

        System.out.println("Requesting pin states...");

        //Requesting pin states on startup.
        try{
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.write("r;");
            out.flush();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        listen();
    }


    //Listening for incoming commands from host
    public static void listen(){
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            socket.getInputStream() ) );
            while(socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()){
                States.commandProcess(in.readLine());
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }


    }

    //send commands.
    static public void send(String command){
        try{
            out.write(command);
            out.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    //closing the socket and resetting the pins on host on close up.
    static public void close(){
        try{
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.write("x;");
            out.flush();
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception exception){
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Thread network = new Thread(new Networking());
    network.setDaemon(true);
    network.start();
    launch(args);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the loops in the defining of the socket and I put recall of the function only in the catch{} part. It seems that the loop was defining more than one socket or something and when I was actually sending data to the socket, it was another socket. Also I changed the thread handling and made it with Task which seems to work a lot better with JavaFX scene.